# Auto complete search result issue in civicrm

Tags: jquery, civicrm

Auto complete search in civicrm does not show any result if the search field contains apostrophe.Any comment(s) would be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you please put the code so we can help you ?

Comment: I have created a select list for a civicrm custom fields and the field is auto completed type. Auto complete functionality working fine all case instated of field item contains apostrophe.

Answer (score 1):

This is a issue in civicrm " drupal_site\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Contact\Page\AJAX.php"

```
 static function autocomplete() {
    $fieldID       = CRM_Utils_Type::escape($_GET['cfid'], 'Integer');
    $optionGroupID = CRM_Utils_Type::escape($_GET['ogid'], 'Integer');
    $label         = CRM_Utils_Type::escape($_GET['s'], 'String');

    $selectOption = CRM_Core_BAO_CustomOption::valuesByID($fieldID, $optionGroupID);

    $completeList = NULL;
    foreach ($selectOption as $id => $value) {
      if (strtolower($label) == strtolower(substr($value, 0, strlen($label)))) {
        echo $completeList = "$value|$id\n";
      }
    }
    CRM_Utils_System::civiExit();
  }
```

Need to remove escape function.

```
$label         = $_GET['s'];
```

Solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

you should escape the string before you add it to the array using the `addslashes();` function in php like this :

**PHP :**

```
$str="this a string with ' ";
$str=addslashes($str);
```

**JS :**

```
var string_from_php=<?php echo $str; ?>
```

and that should work just fin. if you added a snipet from your code that populate the array that gos to the autocomplet i wouldv been much more of a help